# How can I compute integer exponentiation modulo a constant in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, pow

I want to compute **a<sup>b</sup> mod c** where `a`, `b` and `c` are integer values. Is there an efficient way to do this?

`pow(a, b) % c` does not seem to work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: @klutt: I included a reference to this very article in my response. The article provides pseudocode and an implementation in Lua. I thought a C implementation might help programmers visiting this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this task, the `pow` function defined in `<math.h>` is not the right tool for multiple reasons:

- computing large numbers with the `pow()` function may overflow the magnitude representable by the type `double` and the precision will not provide the low order digits that are required for the modulus operation.
- depending on its implementation in the C library, `pow()` might produce non-integral values for integral arguments, whose conversion to `int` could truncate to incorrect values.
- the `%` operation is not defined on the `double` type.
- to avoid losing the low order bits, one should perform the modulus operation at every step.
- for a test, it is not what the examiner expects.

One should instead compute the power and modulus iteratively in a loop:

```c
unsigned exp_mod(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c) {
    unsigned p = 1 % c;
    while (b-- > 0) {
        p = (unsigned long long)p * a % c;
    }
    return p;
}
```

For very large values of `b`, iterating will take a long time. Here is an efficient exponentiation algorithm that reduces the time complexity from **O(b)** to **O(log b)**:

```c
unsigned exp_mod_fast(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c)) {
    unsigned p;

    for (p = 1 % c; b > 0; b = b / 2) {
        if (b % 2 != 0)
            p = (unsigned long long)p * a % c;
        a = (unsigned long long)a * a % c;
    }
    return p;
}
```

As suggested by *rici*, using type `unsigned long long` for the intermediary product avoids magnitude issues for large values of `a`. The above functions should produce the correct results for all 32-bit values of `a`, `b` and `c`, except for `c == 0`.

The initial step `p = 1 % c` is necessary to produce the result `0` for `c == 1 && b == 0`. An explicit test `if (c <= 1) return 0;` might be more readable and would avoid the undefined behavior on `c == 0`. 
Here is a final version with a test for special cases and one less step:

```c
unsigned exp_mod_fast(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c)) {
    unsigned p;

    if (c <= 1) {
        /* return 0 for c == 1, which is the correct result */
        /* also return 0 for c == 0, by convention */
        return 0;
    }
    for (p = 1; b > 1; b = b / 2) {
        if (b % 2 != 0) {
            p = (unsigned long long)p * a % c;
        }
        a = (unsigned long long)a * a % c;
    }
    if (b != 0) {
        p = (unsigned long long)p * a % c;
    }
    return p;
}
```

A more general analysis is available on the Wikipedia article titled [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).